# how to add background color for top and bottom geometry page?

Tags: fancyhdr, titlesec, geometry

I am trying to create a document and somehow I want it to be in color, but it has been difficult for me to try to color the top and bottom, for all pages in general

[image: reference image]

```latex
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,oneside]{book}%
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}%[showframe]

%  edit title and header
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
 
\begin{document}
\chapter{Getting Started}

\section{Preview sect}

\end{document}
```

So far I have managed to create the structure

Comment: Do you really want a background for the headers and footers, or just a coloured zone *above* the header and *under* the footer?

Comment: @Bernard coloured zone above the header and under the footer,I need to fill everything with color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've well understood, it's easy to do with `eso-pic`:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,oneside]{book}%
\usepackage{newpxtext, newpxmath}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}%[showframe]
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

% edit title and header
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[explicit,]{titlesec}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\color{DodgerBlue}%
\AtPageUpperLeft{\rule[-20mm]{\paperwidth}{20mm}}%
\AtPageLowerLeft{\rule{\paperwidth}{25mm}}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Getting Started}

\section{Preview sect}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

*Unrelated*: You don't have to load `amsfonts` when you load `amssymb`. Also, nowadays, you don't have to load `inputenc`: utf8 is now the default. I recommend to load `newpx` rather than `mathpazo`, as it is based on a  `palatino` clone which has more glyphs.

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, you have brightened my day. Thank you very much @Bernard