# Format full header with figure and plain background

Tags: tikz-pgf, header-footer, fancyhdr, eso-pic

I want to configure my page header such as
[image]

I've tried using the eso-pic package suggested in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553044/how-to-add-background-color-for-top-and-bottom-geometry-page), but it seems like it doesn't allow add images or text too.

```latex
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,oneside]{book}%
\usepackage{newpxtext, newpxmath}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}%[showframe]
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[explicit,]{titlesec}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\color{DarkGreen}
\AtPageUpperLeft{\rule[-20mm]{\paperwidth}{20mm}
\begin{picture}(0,0)
{\includegraphics[height=0.6cm,width=0.6cm]{images/ufabc.png}}
\end{picture}}%
}

teste

\end{document}
```

[image]

Could anyone help me find how to make it work with this package or how could I do this in other way?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE and *saudações da UFABC*! This is one or the rare occasions I find someone here not only from Brazil, but also from the university I graduated myself. Are you looking for a header for a subset of pages or for all pages?

Comment: @FHZ greetings from a newbie. This project actually is supposed to be a doc for a code with only one/two pages using this same template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One among many possible solutions is the use of `eso-pic` to draw your style. Notice you may editing the measures or make them automatic to any page geometry your are using.

This solution applies the same background to each page. If your are looking for a header in specific page, I may check how to adapt it using `fancyhdr` for specific cases. I *think* you would like it since you wrote `fancyhdr` and it seems to be a page in a report.

OBS.: As you are writing in Brazilian Portuguese, I suggest using `\usepackage[brazil]{babel}` and `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` (it'd be probably better).

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,oneside]{book}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}[showframe]
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \fill[opacity=1,line width=2pt,DarkGreen]
    ($ (current page.north west) + (0cm,-2cm) $)
    rectangle
    ($ (current page.north east)$);
    \node[opacity=.8, inner sep=0pt] at ($ (current page.north west) + (3cm,-1cm) $)
    {\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{example-image-duck}}; %*(\thepage-1)
    \node[font=\bfseries\LARGE, white] at ($ (current page.north) + (0cm,-1cm) $) {Dicionário de Dados};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Edit**:

Adapting the previous example for `fancyhdr`, you can add your header to the pages you want and only them.

I'd suggest to learn how to [Make your own .sty files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8752/140133) and making this style part of your own library of styles.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,oneside]{book}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}[showframe]
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\pagestyle{mystyle} % fancy, myheadings, headings
\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{ % alteração de estilo pré-definido.
  \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields 
  \fancyhead[R]{\thepage} % except the right top corner 
  \fancyhead[L]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
      \fill[opacity=1,line width=2pt,DarkGreen]
      ($ (current page.north west) + (0cm,-2cm) $)
      rectangle
      ($ (current page.north east)$);
      \node[opacity=.8, inner sep=0pt] at ($ (current page.north west) + (3cm,-1cm) $)
      {\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{example-image-duck}}; %*(\thepage-1)
      \node[font=\bfseries\LARGE, white] at ($ (current page.north) + (0cm,-1cm) $) {Dicionário de Dados};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  } % except the left top corner 
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove line between header and main text
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{C}
\section{S1}
\pagestyle{headings}
\lipsum[1-10]
\clearpage
\section{S2}
\pagestyle{mystyle}
\lipsum[1-10]
\clearpage
\section{S2}
\pagestyle{headings}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

The following picture presents pages 4 and 5, the ones under `\pagestyle{mystyle}`. Pages from other sections don't have it.

[image]

---

*Edit 2*:

Using `\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont` at `\node[font=\bfseries\LARGE, white] at ($ (current page.north) + (0cm,-1cm) $) {\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont Dicionário de Dados};` changes font to [Helvetica](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helvetica), which is very similar to Arial [and not easy to spot differences](https://creativepro.com/helvetica-vs-arial-difference/).

[image]

Comment: The font of your example is probably *Arial* or **Arial black**, is it mandatory to be this font? I used the default font of LaTeX.

Comment: No really, I was actually trying some things before and it ends up in this mess. Thank you very much for your answer @FHZ, I am looking forward for your tip specially for my future bigger projects